# __Impl Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, iis

When I use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(); Sometimes I am returned assemblies from my project that are appended with __Impl

Can someone explain where/how/why these assemblies are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These assemblies ended up being created dynamically by NServiceBus.